# Proper way to parse (prepare) URL for curl

Tags: php, curl

What is proper way to parse URLs for curl?

Let's say i have given URL

```
$url='https://example.com/some url/something?x=1&y=foo/bar#abc';
ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//set all needed more curl parameters
$result=curl_exce($ch);
```

if i put that king of URL in browser, it'll work find. But for me it always returns 404 if it has any non-standard URL characters

sure, i could manually replace spaces with %20 and so on, but that won't do.

curl_escape() will not do too, because it will escape also all slashes and other characters, that should not be escaped in URL, but should be in GET parameters list.

I guess i should probably split this string to parts and threat those separately with differently, but I'm stuck here.

Comment: How is the URL being constructed?  Individual parameters should be escaped, but not the entire URL itself.  It sounds like the logic you want to update is before this code.

Comment: url is not constructed by my code, most of times it's just copy-pasted from browser or obtained in other way by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I parsed the URL into its components, individually encoded the path and query parameters, and then reconstructed the URL for proper handling in a `cURL` request in `PHP`.

```
  $url = 'https://example.com/some url/something?x=1&y=foo/bar#abc';
    
    $parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
    
    $encodedPath = implode("/", array_map("rawurlencode", explode("/", $parsedUrl['path'])));
    
    if (isset($parsedUrl['query'])) {
        parse_str($parsedUrl['query'], $queryParams);
        $encodedQuery = http_build_query($queryParams);
    } else {
        $encodedQuery = '';
    }
    
    $encodedUrl = $parsedUrl['scheme'] . '://' . $parsedUrl['host'] . $encodedPath;
    if (!empty($encodedQuery)) {
        $encodedUrl .= '?' . $encodedQuery;
    }
    if (isset($parsedUrl['fragment'])) {
        $encodedUrl .= '#' . $parsedUrl['fragment'];
    }
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $encodedUrl);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === false) {
        echo 'cURL Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```